# Erro 500 (Internal Server Error) ao fazer upload

Tags: ubuntu, file-upload, nginx

Ao tentar fazer upload de um arquivo txt, estou recebendo o `erro 500`.

Dei um `# chmod -R 777 import` para liberar todas as permissões.
`ls -l` da pasta onde estou tentando salvar o arquivo:

> drwxrwxrwx  2 francisco francisco 4096 Dez  2 12:28 import

Meu `Yii` esta configurado para utilizar `URL-Amigável`:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

E o `Nginx` igualmente configurado:

```
server {

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    listen 127.0.2.1:80;
    listen 192.168.25.33:80;
    root    /usr/share/nginx/meudominio.com;
    index index.php;

    server_name local.meudominio.com;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|framework|themes/\w+/views){
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: A pasta temporária tem permissão? normalmente é a pasta do sistema (/tmp), mas pode ser definida outra em http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir.

Comment: Outro detalhe, se o erro fosse no php/yii seria exibida a mensagem padrão (no layout do Yii). se a mensagem não está sendo exibida no layout do Yii então você pode verificar o log do nginx: http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/

Comment: A pasta temporária tem sim permissão. Na realidade já corrigi esse problema, e respondi lá no SOEN, mas não queria responder aqui justamente para deixar outros responderem(e estou com preguiça).

O erro é na verdade do PHP e um pouco do Nginx. O tamanho do arquivo esta sendo limitado no php.ini como 2M, apesar de no Nginx esta com 20MB(primeira linha do servidor). Apenas alterar `upload_max_filesize` para 20M e resetar o serviço, no meu caso `php5-fpm`.